# jQuery append class to parent TD of input if val is present

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

Pretty much what the title says; I am trying to add icons to shipping selections in Woocommerce, since sometimes the form is filled in on page load. I've created this

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    $('.shipping_method').each( function () {
        $this = $(this).closest('td');
        if ( this.value = 'table_rate_shipping_freship' ) $this.addClass('shipups');        
    });
});
```

This doesn't work, and I'm not sure why.
An additional point is that the shipping method value can change based on information entered further up the form. So would having something like the following be okay?

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    $('.shipping_method').each( function () {
        $this = $(this).closest('td');
        if ( this.value = 'table_rate_shipping_freship' ) $this.addClass('shipups');        
    });
});

$(document).ready( function () {
    $('.shipping_method').change(function() {
        $this = $(this).closest('td');
        if ( this.value = 'table_rate_shipping_freship' ) $this.addClass('shipups');        
    });
});
```

I'm guessing not since it's basically doing what's been done before but adding a .change() to it. Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks.

Edit: By request, the HTML from the Woocommerce checkout relating to shipping method:

```
<tr class="shipping">
    <th>Shipping and Handling</th>
    <td>
            UPS Next Working Day (Free)     <input type="hidden" name="shipping_method[0]" data-index="0" id="shipping_method_0" value="table_rate_shipping_freship" class="shipping_method">
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Show an example of your HTML as the problem may be a typo or mismatch.

Comment: Apologies, I've added this now :).

Comment: First of all, i tried this code in jsFiddle `$(document).ready( function () {
    $('.shipping_method').each( function () {
        $this = $(this).closest('td');
        if ( this.value = 'table_rate_shipping_freship' ) $this.addClass('shipups');        
    });
});` and it works. So maybe you have some errors in console or you forget to add jquery into project?

Comment: Hi, yes, i checked again and it does work but as i said below to veerasuthan V "the page finishes loading then when looks like an Ajax loading gif appears over the shipping section until its checked the delivery address, at this point it strips the class back off the TD."

Comment: @user2546864, maybe there are other script which "strips the class back off the TD" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("input[value='table_rate_shipping_freship']").parent().addClass('shipups');
```

try this. it will add class to parent td

Comment: I tried this and it didnt work until i added a document ready around it, Then it appeared but disappeared when the page finished loading.

Comment: you have to always use $(document).ready( function () {.... if it disappear means you have used some other code which overrides it

Comment: Ok it looks like your code works, but to give more detail, the page finishes loading then when looks like an Ajax loading gif appears over the shipping section until its checked the delivery address, at this point it strips the class back off the TD.

Comment: if you are using ajax which load this td and input elements.. in this case you need to put this after you have insert that elements in the html content. i,e in the success paremeter code of ajax method

Comment: @veerasuthan V: You do not *always* have to use DOM ready. You can also place the script code after the elements it references (e.g. end of `body`) :)

Comment: Got it working, thanks for your help :). I just put it in the correct template, which helped...Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

posted answer working fine,
But if you need something general, here you go :)

```
function addCustomClass(target, className, valueToCheck) {
        $("input[value='" + valueToCheck + "']").closest(target).addClass(className);
    }
```

Usage:

```
addCustomClass('td', 'shipups', 'table_rate_shipping_freship');
```

Comment: Adding an obscurely named function, to do a one-line task, seems counter-intuitive to code maintenance :)

Comment: I wrote something general, just an idea, nothing more :) of course I changed `parent` to `closest`, because maybe the `input` be a child of something else than 'td'